# Can the tape of a Turing machine be represented as a discrete function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, turing-machines

I'm just thinking aloud here, and to expand on this, each square of the tape could lie between integers, and discrete y values of the function could map to symbols. That way a given discrete/step function could describe a given program, and vice versa. I'm playing with ideas of somehow using integration on some analytic analogue of such a function to give some indication on whether the program halts.

Comment: _Discrete_ function, not discreet.

Comment: Wow thanks, not sure what happened there...

Comment: The contents of the tape at a given instant correspond to a function from integers to a set consisting of the symbols and the blank. When the program writes a new symbol on the tape, the tape represents a new function. Neither function describes the program of the machine.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about sounds vaguely close to a form of the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis), that there is a relation between "recursively enumerable" functions (which are a subset of functions applied to the natural numbers) and Turing machines.

When working with Turing machines and decidability, it's important to note that there's a difference between the contents of the tape at any point in time and the machine itself, but also that:

1. Every combination of Turing Machine + initial tape can be reduced to a TM with a blank initial tape;
2. Every TM with an alphabet of $N$ symbols can be reduced to one with only two symbols; and
3. It is generally impossible to prove whether any given TM and input will halt, and the set of TMs that can be proven to halt or not is infinitesimal compared to the set of all TMs.

Comment: Thanks for that. Perhaps if there was a nice way to simulate registers analytically, that might help to complete this functional analogue of TMs? If that makes any sense...

Comment: I'm not going to tell you to stop investigating this, because all inquiry is useful, but there already are quite well-understood mappings between TMs and functions. I forgot to add in my list that you can also restrict TMs to only needing tape that's infinite in one direction, so combining that with a two-symbol alphabet means you can directly map the tape contents to natural numbers, which gives you a link to integer sequences and number theory.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it's a programmer's hobby, I'm reading The Annotated Turing and started wondering about a few things. For instance, and I'm not sure if it's related, but is there a "mathematically nice" way to represent assigning values to variables, or the notion of "storing values in memory" more broadly? For instance a counter inside a for loop in programming. I guess that's what I meant when referring to registers, such as the registers in a CPU. Summation is sort of a for-loop analogue, but the idea of assigning values to a variable inside a for loop?

Comment: And a TM's print command would be the obvious analogue of course, but I guess I'm wondering if there's something that's more amenable to the tools of calculus.

Comment: None of that stuff exists in a pure Turing Machine. Its only input and output are the tape contents, and its only active memory is the state of the machine. All of the things that modern computers do come from building specific functional concepts out of those basics.